# How to test for a statistically significant difference between 3 groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, percentage

**MY PROBLEM:** I need to test for statistical significance between the three groups. The problem comes when extremely large numbers are involved and the chi-square test is always significant. I read several related questions however I didn't find a solution. What test should I use?

1. [How to test for a statistically significant difference between 3 percentages?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169407/how-to-test-for-a-statistically-significant-difference-between-3-percentages)
2. [Which statistical test for statistical significance of positive result in 5 categories of samples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143775/which-statistical-test-for-statistical-significance-of-positive-result-in-5-cate)
3. [How to test for a statistically significant difference between multiple unbalanced groups](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/437244/how-to-test-for-a-statistically-significant-difference-between-multiple-unbalanc)

**MY DATA:** We classify tweets into three different groups if the account is: bot/non-bot/self-declared. Then each of the tweets is classified into 18 different topics. We need to check if there are topics where tweets sent by accounts classified as bots (or non-bots or self-declared) are more common.

The total number of tweets written from each of the groups is:

- Bot           1,106,255
- Non-Bot       8,218,070
- Self Declared 1,101,219

For Topic 14 and Topic 9 the distribution is as follows:

|  | Bot | Non-Bot | Self-Declared |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Topic 14 | 23234 | 192319 | 27585 |
| No Topic 14 | 1083021 | 8025751 | 1073634 |
| Percentage | 2.1% | 2.4% | 2.6% |
|  |  |  |  |
| Topic 9 | 117259 | 940800 | 181543 |
| No Topic 9 | 988996 | 7277270 | 919676 |
| Percentage | 11.9% | 12.9% | 19.7% |

Following this method, we plotted this chart [image]

Comment: General comment about sample sizes and hypothesis testing: huge sample sizes almost always leads to a _statistically significant_ result regardless of the _practical significance_ of the result. You might be better off defining a threshold ($x$%) and if the different in percentage row is more than $\pm x$% you deem the result "meaningful". The choice of $x$ is something a domain expert/you should come up with

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You already mentioned the chi-squared test (or F-test), which would be the appropriate test for multiple equations, i.e. in your case the null would be over the (de-meaned) means or percentages of the 3 groups: $H_0: \hat \mu_1 - \mu= 0; \hat \mu_2 - \mu= 0; \hat \mu_3 - \mu= 0$, which implicitly tests if the groups are the same (i.e. differences zero). If the result is significant then that's your answer: there is a statistically significant difference between the groups. Why are you looking for a different test?

Comment: @PaulG the problem is that with big numbers chi-squared test is always significant.